# Creating java process to execute class within current jar

Tags: java, process, jar, classpath, processbuilder

So hopefully the title covers the jist, I am aware there are multiple posts around this kind of thing, the issue I am specifically having is how to set the classpath for the jar i am currently running which contains the class.

i.e I have packaged my jar with all dependencies exploded within, using the Maven assembly plugin. So I am simply trying to create a sub process to execute one of the dependency classes existing in my jar, from within my jar. If thats possible?

Thanks to the post below here is the solution:

```
URL baseUrl = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
                String myPath = (new File(baseUrl.toURI())).getCanonicalPath();

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("javaw", "-cp", myPath,
 "jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.Main", config.getSuite().getAbsolutePath());

pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

try
{
    Process proc = pb.start();

    InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

    int c;

    while ((c = bis.read()) != -1)
    {
        System.out.write(c);
    }

    int exit = proc.waitFor();
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Is there any compelling reason why you must run your class in a new process? Otherwise it would be very straightforward to just invoke the static main() method of your jp.vmi.selenium.selenese.Main class!

Comment: I am aware of that. I want to run it as a new process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if you absolutely must, you may try this snippet to find your "current" JAR:

```
try
    {
        URL baseUrl = JavaApplication2.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        String myPath = (new File(baseUrl.toURI())).getCanonicalPath();
        System.out.println("Path is " + myPath);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
       // Deal with exception 
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException ex)
    {
       // Deal with exception 
    }
```

Instead of "JavaApplication2" use any class in your application/JAR. (or just getClass(), should also work in non-statical context)